# Running Flask via FastCGI in IIS at application level instead of website leve

Tags: python, flask, iis

I've configured the basic Flask web sample in a VENV and now it is correctly published through IIS via FastCGI.

Well, here it is my trivial sample00.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World, from Flask!"
```

and the web.config, a little more involved:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" 
         scriptProcessor="F:\Appl\flask\venv\Scripts\python.exe|F:\Appl\flask\venv\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" 
         resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
      </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="F:\Appl\flask" />
      <!-- Flask apps only: change the project name to match your app -->
      <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="sample00.app" />
      <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="F:\Appl\flask\wfastcgi.log" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

After some trials and errors, I've discovered that I can enter in IIS Manager > Handler Mappings > select my "PythonHandler", edit the "Executable (optional)", and it checks if the path is correct and asks me to activate the handler, then I can answer "yes" and eventually it all works as expected.

So far so good.
Now, I would like to setup it in IIS not as a separate website, but as a new application under another, existing, website. Is it even possible or is there a documentation saying that it is not permitted? We can close this question or mark it as duplicated, but till now I was not able to find a previous answer to this specific point.
Anyway, I've tried to do that, but I receive a **404** page error... like if the request is not correctly forwarded to the cgi handler, hence I suspect there could be some problem in managing a Flask app at IIS application level, is it the case or what else am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The point is simply that, looking at the Basic Settings in IIS at the application level, see an image sample below,

[image]

the **virtual path** (`/flask` in the above case) is passed from IIS to the FastCGI handler, hence it must be managed in the Flask app, e.g. you can define the route as:

```
@app.route("/flask")
def hello():
```

and it will be correctly shown in your browser (notice that a final `/` would represent a different url though, so such a typo could also cause a 404 error).

The conculsion is that you absolutely **can** run the Flask FastCGI also at application level and not only at website level in IIS.

You also need to add the virtual path before the static file folder:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/flask/static')
```

Finally a suggestion: if you have a configuration like

```
app.config.from_object(Config())
if environ.get('FLASK_FREIGHT_SETTINGS') is not None:
 app.config.from_envvar('FLASK_FREIGHT_SETTINGS')
```

then `iisreset /restart` to make a new env var visible to IIS or - even better -

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

use the [python-dotenv module](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) as above to read the environmental variables from an `.env` file, but I'd also enable the flag to *monitor changes to file* in *fastcgi settings* of IIS at server level, so that your flask application's python handle is reloaded when you update your app_settings.cfg (where I define a version number parameter).

Comment: Btw, see my follow-up answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65872279/11323942): if you want to set an environment variable, do that via the FastCGI Settings of IIS and not from the system control panel.