# Deleting an environmental variable for IIS

Tags: iis, environment-variables, fastcgi

I've understood that, in order to make IIS read a new environmental variable, I have to reset it via an administrator's command:

```
iireset /restart
```

I know that one can also restart IIS from the admin panel at server level.
More context to my complete web app setup in my previous [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64336270/11323942): in brief it is a Python Flask app running on IIS through [WSGI and FastCGI](https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi/).

What is still surprising me is that now, if I **delete** a previously created environmental variable, IIS keep seeing it, even after **restarting** it, as done above.

Why is that possibly happening? And how should I delete the variable for IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist that you want to go with environmental variables (notice that you also have the alternative `.env` file), then you need to set them via the IIS **FastCGI Settings** from the IIS admin at server level for your specific application (the one you enabled via `wfastcgi-enable`).

Edit the specific row as said above and you'll find the Environment Variables collection under the "General" group of FastCGI Properties.

Now you can add and **delete** any of those variables and it will take effect immediately, without the need of any IIS reboot.

Comment: The reason behind is that IIS is a multi-process system. The hosting processes of your Python app are Python processes spin off by IIS FastCGI module, so the variables you configure under FastCGI settings can take effect quickly (other ways to set/inherit environment variables are more complex).